# Jade template language: escaping tags with exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is there way to escape HTML tags in jade string, except for some? For example, I want in my string only `<b>, <i>, <u>, <br/>` tags should be allowed. Now I'm using [this php's strip_tags emulation](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/strip_tags.js) as a mixin, just wondered if there is a native Jade's solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a conditional test over content of your var, then use the bang operator to not excape if content match to your rules, obviously with complex content your conditional test can be really complex

http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode

```
- var varP = '<b>test</b>';
- if (varP.indexOf('<b>') = -1)
    #myTest = varP
- else
    #myTest != varP
```